# Why isn't my search method working in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, where-clause

In my Ruby on Rails application, I have a cinema system and am trying to return the screen a showing is in when a user searches for the showing.

To display the search drop down I am using this code in my _application.html.erb:

```
<%= render( :partial => '/screen_lookup', :locals => {:showings => @showings = Showing.all, :my_path => '/screens/display_screens_by_showing' })%>
```

Which renders the search from the _screen_lookup.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag my_path, :method=>'post', :multipart => true do %>

    <%= select_tag ('showings_id'), 
        options_from_collection_for_select(@showings, :id, :showing_times, 0 ),
        :prompt => "Showings" %> 

    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

And uses the display_screens_by_showing in the screens_controller:

```
  def display_screens_by_showing
    @screens = Screen.showing_search(params[:showing_id])
    if @screens.empty?
        # assign a warning message to the flash hash to be displayed in
        # the div "feedback-top"
        flash.now[:alert] = "There are no films of that genre."
        # return all products, in alphabetical order
        @screens = Screen.all
    end
    render :action => "index"
 end
```

And this searches using the method in the screen.rb model:

```
def self.showing_search(showing_id)
    screen = Showing.where("id = ?", showing_id).screen_id
    self.where("id = ?", screen)
end
```

Now, the problem I am having is that because a showing `belongs_to` a screen, and a screen `has_many` showings, I need to be able to search for the showing, and store that showing's screen_id in a variable to search for the screen that showing is in with, which I have tried doing in the model:

```
screen = Showing.where("id = ?", showing_id).screen_id
self.where("id = ?", screen)
```

But the error I am getting is:

```
NoMethodError in ScreensController#display_screens_by_showing
undefined method `screen_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

These are the model relationships:

showing.rb:

```
class Showing < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :screen
end
```

screen.rb:

```
class Screen < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :showings
end
```

What code will get my search working?

Comment: so when I run `Screen.showing_search(5)` what am I expecting in return ? all the showings that belong to the screen with id = 5 right ?

Comment: Yes, but there should only be the one screen

Comment: yea i edited my comment, does the last one sound right?

Comment: Sort of, I get that its trying to find the showing by the id, but what I want to do is then select that showing's screen_id, and search in the screens table for a screen with that screen_id

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `where` doesn't return a record, it returns a relation that can be enumerated or chained, instead you want to use `find` or `find_by` to return a single record, which is kind equivalent to where + first

```
screen = Showing.find(showing_id).screen_id
```

which is sort of like doing

```
screen = Showing.where(id: showing_id).first.screen_id
```

If you want to pass a hash you can use `find_by` which will be like this

```
screen = Showing.find_by(id: showing_id).screen_id
```

PS:
I'm not sure what you're doing exactly, but i think those two lines can be merged into a single query ( not sure what it should be returning, but I'm assuming a screen )

```
def self.showing_search(showing_id)
    Showing.find(showing_id).screen
end
```

Comment: That gives the error: `TypeError in ScreensController#display_screens_by_showing can't convert nil into String`

Comment: ok so what is this method supposed to return, and what is `nil`? the `showing_id`?

Comment: Ok, what I want it to return is the screen that the selected showing is in. The problem I have is that one screen has many showings, so I do not know how to find the screen a showing is in

Comment: could you the model definitions to the question, just the model names and the relations, for showing and screen